# Android Google MapView shows only empty tiles

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm tying to develop a simple app that shows a map.

I obtained the debug.keystore API-Key and triple checked it for correctness.
I also exported the project as apk and used a custom keystore with associated API-Key.

I have the following permissions set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But on my devices and in the emulator are still only empty tiles showing.

EDIt:
Log Cat:

```
03-19 10:29:09.554: W/System.err(1396): IOException processing: 26
03-19 10:29:09.554: W/System.err(1396): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
03-19 10:29:09.570: W/System.err(1396):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
03-19 10:29:09.570: W/System.err(1396):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
03-19 10:29:09.578: W/System.err(1396):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
03-19 10:29:09.585: W/System.err(1396):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
03-19 10:29:09.593: W/System.err(1396):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
03-19 10:29:09.601: W/System.err(1396):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Theese exceptions repeat rapidly.

Proxy issues or internet problems are not present. The map application works.

maybe somebody can help.

Greets
Henrik

Comment: afaik there is a message about wrong api-key in the log. Do you have that?

Comment: Can you show us your logcat? maybe you have some warnings on errors on it..

Answer (score 4):

The only reason for Empty tiles is the problem with key or proxy or internet issues.

Check if the normal maps application is working perfectly in your simulator. If yes then the problem is with your Key. or else the problem is with proxy or internet.

#### Don't forget to create the simulator with Google API's

Follow the below link care fully for more info.

> http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: The Map key is different for each and every system

Comment: I know. I changed the develop computer and created two new keys. (one for debug keystore, one for custom keystore)

Comment: Thanks Pavandroid, your suggestion of creating a simulator with Google API's has solved the problem. Once I have created the Simulator, it started working in my mobile as well.

Answer (score 2):

I face this problem and Pavandroid is absolutely right. Map Key is the problem in your case. You refer this link, it has step by step explanation of Map Key and Mapview.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112044/GPSLocator-App-to-Find-Current-Nearest-Location-us

Hope this will help you..

Comment: As I said: the API key can't be the problem. I checked it and tried a new one with a not debug certificate and the associated key.

Comment: just the log cat you see above. everything I found in the net said that the API key is wrong but thats not my error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked LogCat? May be you can find errors there with error codes you can trace back to the documentation.
   For eg you could have something like; onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4 and this you can trace over here [ConnectionResult Reference - Google](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult)
2. Make sure your API key is correct. [Google API v2 Signup](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)
3. In case you are using MapView, make sure you are following the proper guidelines. Similar answer here: [Detailed answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263974/onconnectionfailed-connectionresult-geterrorcode-4/38331798#38331798)