# onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4

Tags: android, google-plus

Here i am doing google + integartion.i am using the following code but i am facing the error which is : onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4.So please anybody help me and tell me what i am doing wrong in this code and provide me the solution for this.i will be very thankful to you.I searched a lot but found nothing.I am using the quick sample of Google plus.There is also another problem i am not able to personal information like birthday etc in this code.

```
 public class GooglePlus extends FragmentActivity implements
            ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
        String fb_userId, fb_username;
        SharedPreferences pref;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        private static final int STATE_DEFAULT = 0;
        private static final int STATE_SIGN_IN = 1;
        private static final int STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 2;

        private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

        private static final int DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR = 0;

        private static final String SAVED_PROGRESS = "sign_in_progress";

        // GoogleApiClient wraps our service connection to Google Play services and
        // provides access to the users sign in state and Google's APIs.
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        // We use mSignInProgress to track whether user has clicked sign in.
        // mSignInProgress can be one of three values:
        //
        // STATE_DEFAULT: The default state of the application before the user
        // has clicked 'sign in', or after they have clicked
        // 'sign out'. In this state we will not attempt to
        // resolve sign in errors and so will display our
        // Activity in a signed out state.
        // STATE_SIGN_IN: This state indicates that the user has clicked 'sign
        // in', so resolve successive errors preventing sign in
        // until the user has successfully authorized an account
        // for our app.
        // STATE_IN_PROGRESS: This state indicates that we have started an intent to
        // resolve an error, and so we should not start further
        // intents until the current intent completes.
        private int mSignInProgress;

        // Used to store the PendingIntent most recently returned by Google Play
        // services until the user clicks 'sign in'.
        private PendingIntent mSignInIntent;

        // Used to store the error code most recently returned by Google Play
        // services
        // until the user clicks 'sign in'.
        private int mSignInError;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_plus);
            pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mSignInProgress = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVED_PROGRESS,
                        STATE_DEFAULT);
            }

            mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();

            Handler handle = new Handler();
            handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // resolveSignInError();

                        }
                    });

                }
            }, 1500);

        }

        private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
            // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and
            // connection failed callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our
            // app uses and which OAuth 2.0 scopes our app requests.
            return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, mSignInProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes
            // might
            // be returned in onConnectionFailed.
            Log.i("", "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                    + result.getErrorCode());

            if (mSignInProgress != STATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                // We do not have an intent in progress so we should store the
                // latest
                // error resolution intent for use when the sign in button is
                // clicked.
                mSignInIntent = result.getResolution();
                mSignInError = result.getErrorCode();

                if (mSignInProgress == STATE_SIGN_IN) {
                    // STATE_SIGN_IN indicates the user already clicked the sign in
                    // button
                    // so we should continue processing errors until the user is
                    // signed in
                    // or they click cancel.
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
            }

            // In this sample we consider the user signed out whenever they do not
            // have
            // a connection to Google Play services.

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        /*
         * Starts an appropriate intent or dialog for user interaction to resolve
         * the current error preventing the user from being signed in. This could be
         * a dialog allowing the user to select an account, an activity allowing the
         * user to consent to the permissions being requested by your app, a setting
         * to enable device networking, etc.
         */
        private void resolveSignInError() {
            if (mSignInIntent != null) {
                // We have an intent which will allow our user to sign in or
                // resolve an error. For example if the user needs to
                // select an account to sign in with, or if they need to consent
                // to the permissions your app is requesting.

                try {
                    // Send the pending intent that we stored on the most recent
                    // OnConnectionFailed callback. This will allow the user to
                    // resolve the error currently preventing our connection to
                    // Google Play services.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_IN_PROGRESS;
                    startIntentSenderForResult(mSignInIntent.getIntentSender(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i("",
                            "Sign in intent could not be sent: "
                                    + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    // The intent was canceled before it was sent. Attempt to
                    // connect to
                    // get an updated ConnectionResult.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Google Play services wasn't able to provide an intent for some
                // error types, so we show the default Google Play services error
                // dialog which may still start an intent on our behalf if the
                // user can resolve the issue.
                showDialog(DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.
            Log.i("onConnected", "onConnected");

            // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the
            // user.
            Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

            String personName = currentUser.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentUser.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentUser.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.i("personName", personName);
            Log.i("email", email);
            Log.i("Gender", "" + currentUser.getGender());
            Log.i("Birthday", "" + currentUser.getBirthday());

            // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
            mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;

            /*
             * fb_userId = currentUser.getId(); fb_username =
             * currentUser.getDisplayName(); editor = pref.edit();
             * editor.putString("fb_userId", fb_userId);
             * editor.putString("fb_username", fb_username);
             * editor.putString("social_provider", "google +");
             * 
             * editor.putString("gender", currentUser.getGender());
             * editor.putString("birthday", currentUser.getBirthday());
             * 
             * editor.putString("device_name", "android");
             * 
             * editor.putString("email",
             * Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient)); editor.commit();
             */

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
            // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason.
            // We call connect() to attempt to re-establish the connection or get a
            // ConnectionResult that we can attempt to resolve.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // If the error resolution was successful we should continue
                    // processing errors.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                } else {
                    // If the error resolution was not successful or the user
                    // canceled,
                    // we should stop processing errors.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                }

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    // If Google Play services resolved the issue with a dialog then
                    // onStart is not called so we need to re-attempt connection
                    // here.
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR:
                if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(mSignInError)) {
                    return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(mSignInError,
                            this, RC_SIGN_IN,
                            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    Log.e("",
                                            "Google Play services resolution cancelled");
                                    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;

                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setMessage(R.string.play_services_error)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.close,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            Log.e("",
                                                    "Google Play services error could not be "
                                                            + "resolved: "
                                                            + mSignInError);
                                            mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                                            // mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                                        }
                                    }).create();
                }
            default:
                return super.onCreateDialog(id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey - you have to sign in to google, this error #4, is mostly a sign-in error. Use a gmail id on your android device. Let me know

Comment: I think the first time, you're always going to get error#4 since you've not signed in yet. After you signed in using mSignInIntent, you should hit onConnected()

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I solved in google api console >> consent screen, and adding a Product Name.

I try this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

In the main activity you need change `.addApi(Plus.API, null)` by `.addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())`

Comment: Works for me, only issue is that you can use debug certificate (for API key and Client ID) only if you're an app owner. Invited developers may use only release certificates.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that I had not created the credentials for the app.

Went to Google Developers Console > Credentials > Create New Client ID

filled the corresponding package name and SHA1 for my app, reran the app and then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using MapView, make sure you are following the guidelines
i.e.

"When using the API in fully interactive mode, users of this class must forward all the activity life cycle methods to the corresponding methods in the MapView class. Examples of the life cycle methods include onCreate(), onDestroy(), onResume(), and onPause(). When using the API in lite mode, forwarding lifecycle events is optional. For details, see the lite mode documentation."

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
  super.onLowMemory();
  mapView.onLowMemory();
}
```